# Columnar Transposition Cipher: How to encrypt

Tags: java

Hi I am pretty new to Java and I am trying to figure out how to create a columnar transposition cipher. If you have created one can you show how it is coded. The cipher encrypts by finding printing out a column depending on the index of a key. For example if the key is TAPE then there would be 4 columns by how many ever rows depending on the length of a input string. Then the system would print out depending on which letter comes first in the alphabet, in this case the column A would be printed first then E and so on forth. I need to know how to print out these columns in the order of the key. I know how to create the columns for the input string. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class SortEncrypt {
    public static String key;
    public static char sortKey;
    public SortEncrypt(String theKey) {
        key = theKey;
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        char tempArray[] = key.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);
        /// I am trying to sort the array and the give the index of the character in the sorted array to the same character of the unsorted array.
    }
    public String encrypt(String theString) {
        String s = theString;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; (i * i) < s.length(); i++) {
            y = i;
            x = i + 1;
        }
        // creates x arraylists 
        List<List<Character>> column = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            column.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }   
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TranspositionCipher {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please print out a word for a key and a sentence for a string: ");
        SortEncrypt s = new SortEncrypt(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I tried doing the sorting this way of the key:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class SortEncrypt
{
public static String key;
public static char sortKey;

public SortEncrypt(String theKey){
    key = theKey;
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    char tempArray[] = key.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(tempArray);
    String imp = tempArray.toString();
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(tempArray);
    for (int i = 0; i<imp.length();i ++){
       char a_char = imp.charAt(i);
       if (a_char == a_char){
           int a = key.indexOf(a_char);
           myList.add(a);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(myList);
}
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far, preferably through some Java source code, where the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Sorry @amn I am kinda new to both Java and StackOverflow i updated the post but my code is still not done to completion